# React: Unable to send file to the backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to send an image to the backend but I am getting an error.

I am trying to do it like this:

```
SignupPublicProfileAPICall({
   headerimage: startupFourthStepForm.headerimage
})
...

          <FormFieldFile
            type="file"
            onChange={e => {
              startupFourthStepFormActionHandler({
                headerimage: e.target.files[0],
              });
            }}
          />
```

What I send is this:

```
lastModified: 1559082933991
lastModifiedDate: Tue May 28 2019 16:35:33 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) {}
name: "010919_North-Park_Guava-Queen_Front-View_a072fdd7-f1e9-4ee9-aae6-97b7bb5c2b54_800x454.png"
size: 127234
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

But the weird thing I see is if I do something like this:

`setState({ headerimage: startupFourthStepForm.headerimage });`

And then I log `console.log(state.headerimage)` I get an empty object `{}`.

This is the body of the fetch call:

```
      body: JSON.stringify({
        headerimage,
      }),
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You should create FormData object instead of stringifing headerImage.

```
<FormFieldFile
            type="file"
            onChange={e => {
              let formData = new FormData();
              formData.append('file', e.target.files[0]); // set the proper name of property

              startupFourthStepFormActionHandler({
                headerimage: formData
              });
            }}
          />
```

and then in your  fetch call just replace body with this:

```
body: headerimage,
```